# Why is this <div> hovering over everything else, and how to solve this?

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position

**[JSFiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/mqs01r6x/)**

There is a `div .background-image-div` (containing a `span` holding a full screen background image) with `position:fixed`, so it does not scroll with the page content.

The rest of the page content appears hovering/stacked on the top of the background image. The picture I attached show the problems and the positions I applied to different elements of HTML.

[image]

***SOME EXPLANATION ON PROBLEMS:***

The problems/my questions can be divided into two categories:

1. **The `ul` containing the animating text, and the rest of the content
   (the orange bordered `div` in the picture) should be in the flow**.

   > By **"in the flow"**, I mean they should appear where they are coded
   >   in the markup, that is the orange bordered `div` *after* the blue
   >   bordered `ul`. But what is happening is that the blue bordered `ul` is
   >   **"out of flow"** - it does not appear where it was written in the markup, but is hovering over everything else.
2. **I want the blue bordered `ul` to appear at the bottom of the
   viewport** (the screen without scrolling down at all), **and the orange
   boredered `div` should appear after it - so it is not visible until
   we scroll down on the page**.

   Now i think I will have to get the window height using JQuery and
   apply a `margin-top` of that value to the orange bordered `div`,
   (and something like that on blue bordered `ul` as well)- so i'll get
   to that later. But if you can suggest a CSS only solution, please
   do.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what /where each div is - but as for your 'JQuery' issue - sounds like you could use margin-top:100vh (use viewheight units). But I'm not entirely sure since I'm not quite sure I follow your design properly...

Comment: Yeah the structure is somewhat hard to understand... I managed to push  the big white paragraph down by increasing `.title-slideshow-ul`'s height. Currently the paragraph is 100px from top because the UL is pushing it 100px downwards. Since everything is in `position:fixed` or `absolute`, it's pointless to say "bottom:30px" because the body has no defined height and it's kind of floating.

Comment: Right, this was a little confusing. I decided to rewrite the layout as your code and explanation was hard to follow. Is this how you want it to work? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmkhb9oL/2/). If so I can write up a little answer explaining anything you do not understand.

Comment: @Ruddy Almost! The background image should be fixed. So that it does not scroll when the page is scrolled. That is, when we scroll the page, the content other than the background image should scroll, but the background image should stay where it is in the background, filling up the screen.

Comment: @Zarah So it should be the whole background? Why did you have a div for the background? We can just put it on the `body` and set it as `background`?

Comment: @Ruddy [Like this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php). The image stays in the background, and the rest of the content scrolls over it.

Comment: @Ruddy Actually this is an SSCCE. I have used a full screen background image in this SSCCE for simplicity. In the real web page, instead of the fullscreen background image, I have a full screen background image slideshow in an `ul`. [You can see the `fiddle` for that here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxuotshh/1/).

Comment: @Zarah [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmkhb9oL/3/) Like so?

Comment: @Ruddy Oh yes yes yes! Absolutely! Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it? Will be useful for future visitors. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got there in the end!

So we did a little rewrite of your layout. To make it a little easier we can create a `div` that is acting as a page for us taking up `height: 100%;`. In this we can `position: absolute;` the `ul` element at the bottom.

Next we put the text content under the first page element, with a little styling we put a `width: 90%` and center it using `margin: 10px auto;` this lets us see the background around the `div`.

For the background we can place this on the `body` and get it to resize using the whole page with this little bit of code.

```
background: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

And we are good to go! Any questions just let me know.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.firstPage {
  height: 100%;
}
.title-slideshow-ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: red;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li div h3 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content-other-than-slider {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
}
/**********************************************************************/

/*title Animations*/

.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(2) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(3) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(4) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(5) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(6) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
/* Animation for the title */

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="firstPage">
  <ul class="title-slideshow-ul">
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>qui·e·tude</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>bal·ance</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>com·po·sure</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-other-than-slider">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne errem laboramus vulputate ius, ei sonet fierent qui. Nusquam concludaturque in eos. Te laudem vivendo reformidans vix, ne tantas prompta quaestio vis, illud instructior ne usu. Ei cum velit ceteros principes, et pri tollit
    nusquam.</p>
  <p>Vim mucius consequat ei, nihil voluptua per at. Elitr dolorum definitiones ea est, et eum tacimates imperdiet, no duo partem molestie. Pri saperet accusamus ut. Eirmod tacimates efficiantur per eu.</p>
  <p>Ea recusabo assueverit nec, ex quot ipsum definiebas nam, quot velit dissentiunt vim ne. Magna eligendi accommodare mei et, per aperiri saperet fuisset ex. Cum essent delicatissimi id, sed ea unum scripserit complectitur, duo ad partem fuisset percipit.
    Nam quas graeco lucilius ex, legere doming et nam, usu id oportere efficiendi. Unum dictas elaboraret mei ut. Te tota invidunt postulant usu, usu affert facilis verterem ei.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much! Now I have question in adopting your solution to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wxuotshh/1/) (because that was the original problem, but I had replaced the background image slideshow with an image for simplicity in this SSCCE) - you have applied the background image on the `body`, but my problem is that I don't have one image but an animation of 6 images in `<li>`s in an `<ul>` - so what should I do now?

Comment: @Zarah So you wanted it like this? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmkhb9oL/4/). You can use the `ul` as the background like you have. If you use my code it works just fine pretty much the same as you had it.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you so very much. I am going to try to understand how it's done. i'll post if I have any questions from it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another container for all the content except the image, and put all the content inside it, like in this [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqs01r6x/1/), first the `HTML`

```
<div class="fixed-container">
    <span class="background">Transparent Text</span>
</div>
<div class="absolute-container">
    <ul class="blinking-title-ul">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="other-content">
        Content Dolor Sit Amet ...
    </div>
</div>
```

with this `HTML`, you're separating the background in the `.fixed-container` so it wont scroll down, and all the content in the `.absolute-container`, what you need now is to style the `.absolute-container` with this style

```
.absolute-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

which will make the container the same size as the screen size. Then for the `.blinking-title-ul`

```
.blinking-title-ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

which will make the `ul` have a full screen width, then appear `100px` from the `bottom` and have the `height` of `100px` too, then lastly for the `.other-content`

```
.other-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
}
```

which will make it appear from the `top` for `100%` of the `.absolute-container` height which is right after the `.blinking-title-ul`